# How to get the site name in drupal 6?

Tags: 6

In some situations, I need the site name of a Drupal 6 site which is given while installation of the site.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both Drupal 6 and Drupal 7, you can use [variable_get](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7).
The [CMI](http://groups.drupal.org/deployment-build-systems-change-management) initiative will likely deprecate this function in Drupal 8.

```
$name = variable_get('site_name', '');
```

Notice the blank '' at the end, which is the "default" value, in case a variable isn't defined.

Comment: In Drupal 6, [`variable_get()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/6) has a required second parameter: `$default`.  If you leave this required parameter off, you may get PHP warnings (depending on the PHP error level configured on your server).

Comment: Good point, added this.